# developer sample docker compose up timeout

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying the Chaincode for Developer samples, and running the docker compose up on the runtime, Terminal 1 - Start the network,

fails

orderer      | 2017-11-11 13:48:52.252 UTC [orderer/common/deliver] deliverBlocks -> DEBU 32c [channel: myc] Received seekInfo (0xc420a12e60) start: > stop: >  from 172.18.0.3:33048
ERROR: compose.cli.errors.log_timeout_error: An HTTP request took too long to complete. Retry with --verbose to obtain debug information.
If you encounter this issue regularly because of slow network conditions, consider setting COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT to a higher value (current value: 60).

this is running on ubuntu 16.04. I don't see anything that would stop connections, the compose file looks right. everything was just downloaded yesterday Nov 10.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a major error in terms of actually running the sample - it's an error occasionally thrown by Docker Compose itself.  As the error says, you can simply set the variable prior to running the sample(s):

```
export COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT=600
```

Comment: now from chaincode, (step 2) get error 2017-11-11 15:42:03.720 UTC [shim] func1 -> ERRO 003 Received error from server, ending chaincode stream: rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service protos.ChaincodeSupport

Comment: I reinstalled the docker containers (now at 1.0.3) and all works ok.

Comment: Glad to hear it